# Superbabies can walk right from birth. How many times are they stronger than a normal baby?

Tags: science-based, humans, genetic-engineering, bio-mechanics, trans-humanism

XXIII century genetic engineering creates superbabies that can walk straight out of the LDR (labor, delivery, and recovery) room right after being born.

These superbabies are enhanced by a set **integer** multiplier gene for each modified characteristic, which, to prevent negative feedback, was set to the minimum necessary for that feat above. This set of multipliers increases

- strength,
- agility,
- coordination (includes balance),
- and basic brain motor functions

by different amounts. The multiplier value is an integer, rounded up if needed.

How many times stronger does each of the multipliers acting on superbaby's body needs to be for it to happen?

Comment: The primary issue is coordination, not physical strength. The modifier therefore is 1 - the baby is already strong enough to walk, it just can't use its limbs in a way that walking requires. And coordination requires learning (self-learning), as while the baby is in the womb, it does not know gravity as it's suspended in midwater. For coordination therefore, the modifier is infinity. Pity.

Comment: @Vesper a newborn can't even hold his/her head using neck muscles. I doubt the multiplier is 1.

Comment: @L.Dutch again, this is a gravity effect vs untrained or unused muscles. And, I've witnessed a hold of a newborn baby on a mother's finger - there was quite some strength. The baby was 1 month old, so not a newborn, but still, fingers are not used by babies normally, yet there is muscle strength ready to use.

Comment: A lot of things happen during the first months beyond mere coordination and the increase in strength. A lot of bones are also still forming/developing in the hands and feet.

Comment: This is answered in the [documentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superbabies:_Baby_Geniuses_2) starring Jon Voight.

Comment: It's not just the ability to walk, it's the knowledge of when and where to walk to not get injured or lost and the (relative) emotional maturity to handle the inevitable mishaps.  A newborn won't have any of that, unless their only partially formed brain is being overridden by some kind of adult-experience mind implant (which would prevent them going through the process of learning).

Comment: After all, he won't be a baby for long. Pretty soon he'll grow up, to become a [superbaby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkoNXfEE8VI).

Comment: Are we allowed super mothers? If we are, what traits do they have?

Comment: @Vesper grip strength is a special case when it comes to newborns. It's believed to be a holdover from when our primate ancestors carried their babies in their fur, and doesn't indicate that the rest of a babies muscles are developed enough to allow for strength.

Answer (score 4):

Main problem is not with strength or agility. Coordination is enough to walk in day or two after birth, brain is developed enough to have basic motor function right after birth. Only problem is size and mass of head.
Head is so big that neck have problem to handle it. Second; head is so heavy that body can't counterpart that weight.
2 solutions:

1. Make head smaller - lower intelligence and so on.
2. Make body bigger - need artificial womb to grow child till birth because of big risk for mother.

No other modifications needed. Adult will be same strong.

Comment: Making the neck stronger will make the head easier to support, and an increase in coordination, even if it has to be extremely high, will allow the large head to be balanced

Answer (score 3):

**This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609)**

What are all the things that need to happen to allow a newborn baby to walk?

- Muscle strength, which means increased muscle length to provide the needed leverage for walking and balance (bigger baby).
- Stronger cartilage and ligaments to handle the stress, requiring more space for connections to bones (bigger baby).
- Bigger circulatory system to deliver the higher oxygen and nutrition requirements (bigger baby).
- Larger digestive system and more developed digestive system to provide the necessary nutrients and energy (bigger baby).
- More widely spaced eyes to provide the necessary 3D rendering to walk upright (bigger baby).
- Better developed hearing to provide for balance and reasonable safety during the more complex task of walking (bigger baby).
- Stronger bones to handle, not just the baby's weight, but also the increased force from walking, jogging, running, jumping, turning, twisting, shuffling, and all the other remarkably complex motions we're all taking for granted because we're trained to them to the point we no longer think about them (bigger baby).
- More capable brain to handle the increased data input and processing necessary for coordinating everything I just discussed (bigger baby).

1. I'm sure you've noticed by now that what you need is a *bigger baby.* More specifically, you need an [12-month-old baby](https://www.webmd.com/baby/when-does-a-baby-start-walking) (basic average) to come out of the mother's womb, thereby turning the mother into something akin to Herbert's [Axolotl Tank](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Axlotl_Tank). So, from one perspective, the ratio you're looking for (since we're forced to use integers) is ***12*** (as in, 12-months-old) and every characteristic would require that same multiplier. But that's a meaningless multiplier that I'm using only to make a point.
2. You're also ignoring that babies are proportionately the wrong shape to walk. Their legs aren't long enough. I mentioned that before (more generically), but it deserves a giant underscore. Yes, that wouldn't stop them from "walking." Yes, people born with [disproportionate dwarfism](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-many-types-of-dwarfism-are-there-2860725) can walk, even run. But I very much doubt that's what you had in mind when you asked the question.

**Pre-Conclusion**

It's not unreasonable to achieve what you're asking for, but it's very much unreasonable to assign some simple integer multipliers to anything but a long list of attributes and hope that what you get is a newborn with the power to walk like a small adult. Remember, you asked for a Science-Based answer, and what science teaches us is that you need an 12-month-old baby to walk.

It's not just an issue of stronger muscles and a brighter mind. The child that comes out of that mother's womb must be *older and more experienced.* You can handwave the experience by saying that it's genetically encoded into the child, but I don't even want to think about what must change physiologically and mentally for a woman to bear such a large and heavy child in any period of time.

**Conclusion**

What you're asking for is opinion-based. Some of those multipliers don't have enough (if any) research to draw from to rationally assert a value. How, for example, do you measure the cognitive capacity of a newborn and compare it to the cognitive capacity of a one-year-old? I very much doubt any research exists that can objectively create such a ratio. I'd be willing to accept such a number from a PhD-holding researcher with decades in the field of newborns-to-one-year-olds — maybe.

So, pick some numbers out of a hat and move on.

Comment: the change in spacing on a toddlers eyes vs a newborns is not much, and is much smaller than the natural variation in toddlers, so that should have little to do with walking.

Comment: @John So we're both guessing? Any change is significant compared to a toddler. But more to the point... you might have missed my point.

Answer (score 0):

## Strength needs to be doubled.

Babies typically start walking around 12 months, and typically have doubled in size by then. As such, a baby that is twice as strong will be able to walk.

## Agility and brain functions needs to triple

Brain size increases roughly three times in the first year. As such, you need three times the brain power to control movement.